# Scalable File Storage

Tags: php, file, mongodb, filesystems, storage

I'm looking for a way to store files, namely images(maybe videos) in a scalable file system. I know I can store it in a cloud, but I am looking for something similar to MongoDB GridFS, but purely for files and scaled across multiple servers.

Not sure if it matters, but the language is PHP.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First thing that comes into my mind is Amazon S3, but I have no experience with it.

Comment: I'm discarding it, I want to know of different solutions that might be more suited to the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook is based on php language and they develop the cassandra for that and more issues... it's based as i read on the bigtable from google.

Also i use mongodb and i love the schema-free that it has to store docs and more info but not videos and of course i use several machines to replicate the system and improve a future growth

Comment: Is Cassandra than MongoDB at file storage?

Comment: I use Mongodb as a document storage because of its schena free system... if you want to store video files you can use the MongoBin data to store them. Also Cassandra is a more powerful yet engine but the technical requirements are also more heavy than installing and using the powerfull MongDb

Answer (score 3):

What about 'classic' distributed file systems like Ceph, Lustre or GlusterFs. They balance the data over a set of servers and can be fault-tolerant.